# How do you make a Table Responsive in CSS when containing images?

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for quite a while and believe its achievable with the use of "Skeleton CSS"

Its a simple concept but proving hard to achieve. I just need a table which contains multiple images (pictured below) to change down to an example width, say 750px if displayed on a smaller screen.

http://s11.postimg.org/6w5cb39ur/Screen_Shot_2015_01_28_at_21_54_28.png

Whats happening at the moment is its staying fixed. This is because I have just sliced from PSD and saved for web.

I don't mind the images scaling down in size as its only for tablet (754px) and desktop (960px). Further to this, it doesn't have to scale down in size, i just need it to jump from one width to the other.

The current html is:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="960" height="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/home_maingrid_01.png" width="310" height="160" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/home_maingrid_02.png" width="15" height="500" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
```

and so on…

I'm not asking for a full blown answer, just what direction to go in so I don't waste time.

Its for a Magento homepage so that different features can go in. I have a different store view for mobile which is why only 960px and 754px are the widths I need to worry about.

Comment: what happens is the img have fixed pixel size so it wont scale as u want ,instead u can give size to the table-cell and make the img `max-width: 100%` and it will scale to the whole cell even when u resize the window ,also keep in mind that html table tags arent actually meant for the web ,instead u can use the css declaration which give much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the width and height from the img and table tag, and in your CSS set

```
img {
width:100%;
}
```

and then set the width of the table to what you need, but make each  a PERCENTAGE of the table; i.e:

```
table {
    width:960px;
    height:500px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 754px){
    table {
        width:500px;
        height:330px;
    }
}
```

> ^(set this to whatever you need)^

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was after, just that it was possible. I have it working now. Height: Auto as well.